# In open source software, what is the concept of "ready when it's ready" called?

Tags: contributor

I remember seeing in several open source projects, particularly smaller ones, that it is discouraged to ask for a timeline or deadline for a particular feature or release, because "it'll be ready when it's ready" and everyone working on it is a volunteer working in their spare time.

What is this concept called? Are there any articles or other resources that explain it? I searched around but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I would call it common sense.

Comment: "Common sense" is often outsourced these days, for better or worse. So it will be helpful to point people to an external resource that explains this concept.

Comment: I don't think there's a name for it. If you're looking for an answer for folks who get impatient, "everyone working on it is a volunteer working in their spare time" should work just fine, with an added "If you're looking for a task to help with, let me know."

Comment: The concept of Open Source is that you can add it yourself. You're not dependent on the timeline of somebody else. It's entirely reasonable to ask if someone has a timeline for the feature, to prevent two competing implementations. And if someone _is_ working on the feature, you can probably help with testing.